Are questions related to “jam resistance” on-topic at Crypto.SE?
Jam resistance for omni-directional wireless networks is something that could be considered “somewhat related to cryptography”. 
It has been subject to ample research over the years (with DARPA diving into “jam resistance” since 2014) and there area ample related publications (some of which can be found via IACR).
A search for “jamming attack” or “jam resistance” via your favorite search engine will probably do a better job than me, listing only a few of a truckload of papers:

“Concurrent Code Spread Spectrum: Theory and Performance Analysis of Jam Resistant Communication without Shared Secrets”, William L. Bahn, Ph.D. Dissertation, University of Colorado at Colorado Springs, Colorado, Nov 2012.
“The Glowworm hash: Increased speed and security for BBC unkeyed jam resistance”, Leemon C. Baird III, Martin C Carlisle, William L. Bahn and Eric Smith, 2012 IEEE Military Communications Conference (MILCOM12), Boston, Massachusetts.
“Unkeyed jam resistance 300 times faster: The Inchworm hash”, Leemon C. Baird III, Martin C Carlisle, William L. Bahn, 2010 IEEE Military Communications Conference (MILCOM12), San Jose, California, 31 Oct - 03 Nov 2010.
“An O(log n) running median or running statistic method for use with BBC jam resistance”, Leemon C. Baird III and William L. Bahn, Technical Report USAFA-TR-2009-ACCR-03, Nov 2009.
“An efficient correlator for implementations of BBC jam resistance”, Leemon C. Baird III and William L. Bahn, Technical Report USAFA-TR-2009-ACCR-02, Nov 2009.
“Parallel BBC decoding with little interprocess communication”, Leemon C. Baird III and William L. Bahn, Technical Report USAFA-TR-2009-ACCR-01, Nov 2009.
“Hardware-centric implementation considerations for BBC-based concurrent codecs”, William L. Bahn and Leemon C. Baird III, Technical Report USAFA-TR-2008-ACCR-03, United States Air Force Academy, Dec 2008.
“Extending critical mark densities in concurrent codecs through the use of interstitial checksum bits”, William L. Bahn and Leemon C. Baird III, Technical Report USAFA-TR-2008-ACCR-02, United States Air Force Academy, Dec 2008.
“Security analysis of BBC coding”, Leemon C. Baird III and William L. Bahn, Technical Report USAFA-TR-2008-ACCR-01, Dec 2008.
“Secure Jam Resistant Key Transfer: Using the DOD CAC Card to secure a radio link by employing the BBC jam resistant algorithm”, Stephen S. Hamilton and John A. Hamilton Jr., 2008 IEEE Military Communications Conference (MILCOM08), San Diego, California, 17-19 Nov 2008.
“Oscillator mismatch and jitter compensation in concurrent codecs”, William L. Bahn, Leemon C. Baird III, and Michael D. Collins, 2008 IEEE Military Communications Conference (MILCOM08), San Diego, California, 17-19 Nov 2008.
“Jam-resistant communications without shared secrets”, William L. Bahn, Leemon C. Baird III, and Michael D. Collins, 3rd International Conference on Information Warfare and Security (ICIW08), Omaha, Nebraska, 24-25 Apr 2008.
“Visually understanding jam resistant communication”, Dennis L. Schweitzer, Leemon C. Baird III, and William L. Bahn, Proceedings of the 3rd International Workshop on Visualization for Computer Security, 29 Oct 2007.
“Keyless jam resistance”, Leemon C. Baird III, William L. Bahn, Michael D. Collins, Martin C. Carlisle, and Sean C. Butler, Proceedings of the Eighth IEEE SMC Information Assurance Workshop (IAW), pages 143-150, West Point, New York, 20-22 Jun 2007.
“Jam-resistant communication without shared secrets through the use of concurrent codes”, Leemon C. Baird III, William L. Bahn, and Michael D. Collins, Technical Report USAFA-TR-2007-01, United States Air Force Academy, 2007.
“A jam-resistant UWB-OFDM system for wireless communications”, Chen Xu, Nantong Univ. China,Wireless Communications, Networking and Mobile Computing, 2005. Proceedings. 2005 International Conference on  (Volume:1 ) 
“Visually Understanding Jam ResistantCommunication”, Dino Schweitzer, Leemon Baird, and William Bahn, Academy Center for Information Security (ACIS), United States Air Force Academy, 2007

Most jam-resistant systems use a secret spreading sequence, a secret hop sequence, or some other kind information that must be kept secret from the jammer. Currently, the only system for achieving such jam resistance without any shared secret is BBC coding. BBC requires the use of a hash function that is fast and “secure”.
Now… since the term “secure” is used in a different sense than for standard cryptographic hashes, it is unclear to me if questions related to BBC coding and/or jam questions would be on-topic here at Crypto.SE or not.
Long story, short question…
Are Q&As related to “jam resistance” (and related questions about “jamming attacks” et al) on-topic and do we consequently accept questions related to “BBC coding”? If we don’t, which SE site would be more appropriate to ask related questions?

Due to the lack of feedback, I’ll try to answer this myself…
Based on the fact that jam resistance partly resides in the realms of cryptography, and partly in the realms of information security, “on topic”-ness will strongly depend on what exactly is being asked:

As some security parameters are well known in cryptography, several aspects related to algorithm design are very well be on-topic here.
Practical implementation will mostly tend to lean towards StackOverflow (think: “coding” questions). 
Questions related to practical application (meaning: “when” and “how” to use jam resistance) are bound to be more on-topic at Security.SE – which is along the lines we handle alike questions.

This should wrap it up until something else comes up somewhere at our Meta and contradicts this.

In short: YES
